# How to select value that matches all values in a list?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get two separate row values, for 2 conditions on the same column.

for example with this data:

```
id       status
----------------
1        0
1        2
1        3
2        2
2        0
```

I want to select all the rows where the `status = 0`, and `status = 2`.

So for example the output should be:

```
id       status
----------------
1        0
1        2
2        0
2        2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just use `where status in (0, 2)`?

Comment: There is no row with `id = 0` in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
where status in (0, 2)
```

But I suspect you want *both* values for the `id`.  In that case, one method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where status in (0, 2) and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.status in (0, 2) and
                    t2.status <> t.status
             );
```

If you just want the `id`s, then aggregation is easy:

```
select id
from t
where status in (0, 2)
group by id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This can be incorporated in a query to get the original rows using `in`, `exists`, or `join`.  Or window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where status in (0, 2)) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2`, you can filter and get the `id`, and based on the `id`s using sub query with `WHERE` clause you can achieve the expected output:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM TableName
    WHERE status IN (0, 2)  
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2 
) AND status IN (0, 2)
```

Working demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=735a4f69f8aeb4998da0dcb22b2780ec)

Answer (score 0):

To get the ids that you want you need to group by id and count the distinct values of status:

```
select * from tablename
where 
  status in (0, 2)
  and
  id in (
    select id from tablename
    where status in (0, 2)
    group by id
    having count(distinct status) = 2
  )
```